# A reverse proxy that automatically gets certificates for the domain that the request comes from

Tags: web-server, nginx

I'm looking for a reverse proxy like nginx, haproxy, etc. that automatically gets a certificate for a domain.

I need this so that I can let users set up their own domain easily. So people can point any domain to the IP, and if someone sends a request to foo.com, which is pointed to the IP, the proxy gets a certificate for foo.com, caches it, and uses it to sign the request.